# Why does B 25 or BEQ 25 in ARM assembly language mean "go to PC + 8 + 100"

Tags: assembly, arm, branch, cpu-architecture, machine-code

I am a beginner and I am studying 32-bit ARM as a part of my Computer Organization course. The meaning for `B 25` or `BEQ 25` is given as `go-to PC + 8 + 100`. I understand what that `100` means. It is the offset, as ARM is byte addressed we need to increment the Program Counter by `25*4`. But what does that `+8` mean? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: In most flavours of asm source languages, `b 25` would be a branch to absolute address 25.  So I assume you mean that as a way of describing ARM-mode machine code, where the `25` is encoded into a field of the instruction word.  I think the `+8` is because they're misusing `PC` to mean the address of *this* instruction, not the PC value this instruction would read if it were `mov r0, pc` for example.  (Unless ARM branches work differently from how I thought.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the response. ARM LEGv8 works the way you say but I guess in LEGv7 it doesn't move to the absolute address but an address calculated by the offset.

Comment: My point in the first part was that writing `b 25` and assembling it would make the assembler calculate the relative displacement necessary to read absolute address `25` from here, wherever here is.  (If it's even in range for a limited size relative offset at all.)  Of course the machine code uses relative branches, and you can write `b . + 100` or `b label` to get the assembler to encode a branch instruction to this-instruction-start + 100 bytes, or to whatever label.  The encoding probably takes advantage of the fixed-size and alignment of insns by left shifting by 2 when decoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real pipeline reasons possibly but today for reverse compatibility the pc is "two ahead".  Two instructions ahead and for full sized instructions that is 4+4 or 8 bytes.  Think fetch, decode, execute, by the time you get to execute the pc is two ahead.

Assembly language is specific to the assembler not the target.  B 25 is a strange operand on that branch instruction, but based on your question the assumption is that is the immediate encoded in the instruction which is units of words.  The destination address would then be PC (OF THE B 25 INSTRUCTION!!!) plus 25*4 plus 8.  25 * 4 is because 4 bytes per word.  So the destination address is PC of the instruction plus 100 plus 8.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <skip-0x24>:
   0:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   4:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   8:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
   c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  10:   ea000003    b   24 <skip>
  14:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  18:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  1c:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
  20:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)

00000024 <skip>:
  24:   eafffffe    b   24 <skip>
```

The encoding here:

```
  10:   ea000003    b   24 <skip>
```

shows a 3 as an immediate and the address of the instruction is 0x10 so

```
0x10 + (3*4) + 8 = 0x10+12+8= 0x10+20 = 0x10+0x14 = 0x24
```

this one has a negative number encoded 0xFFFFFFFE times 8 is 0xFFFFFFF8

```
  24:   eafffffe    b   24 <skip>
```

so 0x24 + 0xFFFFFFF8 + 8 = 0x24

Note that b 24 in the disassembly means branch to address 0x24 not the 25 like your question implies as an immediate.

And for thumb mode they did two ahead as well with 16 bits or two bytes per instruction, 4 bytes ahead 2+2.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <skip-0x12>:
   0:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   2:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   4:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   6:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   8:   e003        b.n 12 <skip>
   a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   c:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
  10:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

00000012 <skip>:
  12:   e7fe        b.n 12 <skip>
```

so for this one (two bytes per instruction so 3 * 2)

```
   8:   e003        b.n 12 <skip>
```

0x08 + (0x3<<1) + 4 = 0x08 + 0x6 + 4 = 0x12

Other instruction sets might fake the pc during execution to be address of the instruction, or most often you see it pointing at the next instruction.  It is all arbitrary, it is what it is and your code or certainly the machine code offsets have to conform to the architecture.

Short answer look at the acorn docs, three stage pipeline, so think fetch, decode, execute so by the time you execute the pc is fetching two instructions ahead.  And the non-acorn ARM continued with that scheme despite having deeper pipes.

Instructions a,b,c,d (not real instructions just for demonstration purposes)

```
0x10 a
0x14 b
0x18 c
0x1C d

PC
0x10 fetch a
0x14 fetch b decode a
0x18 fetch c decode b execute a
0x1C fetch d decode c execute b
```

So instruction a lives at address 0x10 but when it executes the pc is 0x18.  This is the 8 byte difference that gets added into the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

When the first ARM CPU was built, they did it as simple as possible.

And the most simple design (requiring the least number of transistors) resulted in the value *(address of current instruction + 8)* for nearly (*) all instructions reading the register `r15`.

For this reason, the instruction `ADD R15, R15, #100` (on those old ARM CPUs) would jump to the address of the current instruction plus `108`.

For compatibility to already existing programs this was not changed in newer ARM CPUs.

---

(*) by the way:

For some instructions the result was officially *(address of current instruction + 12)*. On newer ARM CPUs, these instructions (such as `ADD r0, r15, r1, lsl r2`) result in an "unpredictable value" when reading `r15`.

So there are indeed some instructions that were leading to a predictable result on the first ARM CPUs which do not result in a predictable result on modern ARM CPUs any more.